# Resultset de una consulta en java

Tags: java, oracle, jsp

Hola tengo un proyecto en el cual en una clase java, realizo la consulta a la bd de oracle, este lo hice de tipo ResultSet, para que mi servlet que funciona como controlador, pudiera discriminar el resultado y ver a donde lo redirige, la consulta solo trae un dato 0 o 1, el problema es que no se como revisar el resultado de la consulta, la idea es pasarla a una variable y comparar con un if la variable que pase el resultado (n) me sale en rojo diciendo como error CANNOT FIND SYMBOL, adjunto el código.

```
 ResultSet rs =consult.getConsultCambioBtnCollectRv(Parametro);
           try {
              if(rs != null){
               while(rs.next()){
                int  n = Integer.parseInt(rs.getString("collection_required_bool"));
                if(n == 0){
                      response.sendRedirect("test.jsp");
                      processRequest(request, response);
                  }else{
                       response.sendRedirect("test1.jsp");
                      processRequest(request, response);
                  }
                }
              }
             } catch (SQLException ex) {
              Logger.getLogger(SvrModificaCollectRv.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
          }
```

Answer (score 1):

Lo primero que veo es que tu código no tiene mucho sentido. Al parecer la sentencia SQL que ejecutas solo debería traer un resultado, pero aplicas un `while` para leerlo. Si no es el caso, entonces deberías utilizar un `if`:

```
if (rs.next()) {
    //...
}
```

No deberías parsear la cadena que obtienes desde la base de datos, deja esa tarea al driver:

```
//int  n = Integer.parseInt(rs.getString("collection_required_bool"));
int n = rs.getInt("collection_required_bool");
```

Veo que ejecutas el método `processRequest(request, response)` luego de indicar el redirect. Una vez que llamas al método `redirect`, no deberías llamar a ningún método adicional para escribir información adicional a la respuesta (`HttpServletResponse response`) puesto que la respuesta será un redirect.

```
response.sendRedirect("test.jsp");
//processRequest(request, response);
```

No estás cerrando el `ResultSet` apropiadamente. Lo mejor sería que utilices el `try` con recursos, o si utilizas Java 6 o anterior pues que cierres el objeto manualmente.

Bajo estas recomendaciones, el código final sería como sigue:

```
try (ResultSet rs = consult.getConsultCambioBtnCollectRv(Parametro)) {
    if (rs != null && rs.next()) {
        int  n = rs.getInt("collection_required_bool"));
        if (n == 0) {
            response.sendRedirect("test.jsp");
        } else {
            response.sendRedirect("test1.jsp");
        }
    }
} catch (SQLException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(SvrModificaCollectRv.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
```

Sin embargo, vemos que hay un problema cuando no se obtienen resultados del `ResultSet`, no se indica qué debe hacerse. Lo mejor sería aplicar una pequeña refactorización y tener como variable la página a la que debería redirigirse por defecto. Aquí un ejemplo:

```
String paginaRedirect = "test1.jsp";
try (ResultSet rs = consult.getConsultCambioBtnCollectRv(Parametro)) {
    if (rs != null && rs.next()) {
        int  n = rs.getInt("collection_required_bool"));
        if (n == 0) {
            paginaRedirect = "test.jsp";
        }
    }
} catch (SQLException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(SvrModificaCollectRv.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
//de esta manera siempre se hará un redirect
response.sendRedirect(paginaRedirect);
```

Answer (score 0):

`n` no será visible en ningún otro ámbito que no sea dentro del `while` ya que es allí donde la estas declarando, para que lo puedas ver en el ámbito del `if` debes declarar `n` (por ejemplo) junto con el `ResultSet`.

Inicialmente tu variable `rs` se inicializa con valor `null` por lo que asumo que en tu método `consult.getConsultCambioBtnCollectRv(Parametro)` se encuentra algo como lo siguiente

```
public ResultSet getConsultCambioBtnCollectRv(...) {
    Statement statement = connection.getConnection().createStatement();
    resultSet = statement.executeQuery(sqlString);
    return resultSet;
}
```

De manera que lo conveniente sería, validar que el resultSet no tenga valor `null` así sabemos que realmente tiene algo que podemos intentar acceder.

```
int n = -1; //valor inicial que desees 

try {
    ResultSet rs = null;
    rs = consult.getConsultCambioBtnCollectRv(Parametro);

    if(rs != null) {
        while(rs.next()){
            n = rs.getInt(1); //obtengo n (siempre y cuando la posicion (1) sea un entero desde la BDD
        }

        if(n == 0) { 
        // my logica aqui 
        }

    } else {
        //Imprimir mensaje, no se pudo obtener datos 
    }
} catch (SQLException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(SvrModificaCollectRv.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
```

También te recomiendo seguir trabajando dentro del `try/catch` por si algo va mal, la aplicación no detenga su ejecución de manera brusca.

Comment: Hola Rosendo, igualmente declarando la variable, esta me muestra error al momento de hacer el if, no se de que otra manera poder evaluar n = rs.getInt(1); para saber si lo que trae es 1 o 0

Comment: @elsa te muestra el mismo error? Dudo que lo sea, porfa actualiza tu pregunta con los cambios realizados y el error, supongo que es un `count` lo que estas haciendo no?

Comment: ¿No sería mejor mover ese `if` dentro del ciclo `while`? Fuera del ciclo while no tiene mucho sentido, a menos que se utilice `if (rs.next())`.

Comment: Desconozco si la consulta trae uno o más resultados y si de traer varios `n` debe ser evaluado para todos.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza he actualizado el codigo, si bien ahora no me muestra error, este no realiza nada, por el navegador me fijo que se queda en el servlet y no se va a ninguna parte.

Comment: @RosendoRopher la consulta trae solo un dato, de valor int que es 0 o 1, por ello solo pido el indice 1, no se si estara correcto de la manera que lo hago

Comment: @Elsa no entiendo por qué llamas al método `processRequest` luego de ejecutar `response.sendRedirect`. Te recomiendo eliminar esa parte y probar nuevamente tu código.

Comment: @RosendoRopher conocer o no conocer lo que devuelva esa consulta no significa que el código que nosotros proveamos en la respuesta carezca de sentido lógico...

Comment: Voy a omitir respuestas a tu comentario @LuiggiMendoza

Comment: @RosendoRopher 
y LuiggiMendoza
Gracias por su ayuda, ya resolví el problema, el la clase que tenia la consulta, evalué el resultado cambiando el metodo de ResultSet a Boolean, retornando true si es 0 y false si es 1, cabe mencionar que lo hice gracias a sus aportes.
muchas gracias <3
   if(rset != null){      while(rset.next()){
  int  n = Integer.parseInt(rset.getString("collection_required_bool"));
                    if(n == 0){
                        resp = true;
                    }else{
                        resp = false;
                    } } }

Answer (score 0):

Podrias hacer algo así:

```
int  n = 0;
ResultSet rs =consult.getConsultCambioBtnCollectRv(Parametro);
while (rs.next()){
      n = Integer.parseInt(rs.getString("collection_required_bool"));
    }

if(n == 0){
      response.sendRedirect("test.jsp");
      processRequest(request, response);
}else{
      response.sendRedirect("test1.jsp");
      processRequest(request, response);
}
```